# Why is destructor for a form called twice?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

This code with entry point calls form's destructor twice.

```
void Main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    MyApp::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

I have changed it to

```
void Main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application::Run(gcnew MyApp::MyForm);
}
```

The second version calls destructor one time only.

Why initially was it called twice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
   MyApp::MyForm form;
```

That's quite wrong.  Knowing when to use the ^ hat on a variable declaration is super-duper important in C++/CLI.  When you don't use it, like you did here, then you invoke "stack semantics".  It is an emulation of the C++ RAII pattern, the compiler automatically emits a call to the destructor at the end of Main().

But that should not happen, the destructor of the MyForm object is automatically called when you close the window.  So in your case you see it running twice.  Not actually fatal, very unlike native C++, unless you do something non-trivial with native code in the destructor.  Keep in mind that the destructor of a ref type doesn't have anything to do with object destruction, that's the job of the garbage collector.  It is only meant for cleanup of native resources.

More about stack semantics in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177191.aspx).

Comment: Thank you! I've taken it from from [this tutorial](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/application_visual_studio_2013.php) when initially couldn't locate Visual C++ Windows Forms application in Visual Studio 2013. It worked for a while until I put `GCHandle::Free` method from `System.Runtime.InteropServices` to destructor. And then as a result of double invocation it was throwing `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: Ugh.  I sent him an email, hopefully he'll fix his tutorial.  Please close your question.

Comment: Aaaaand ... he ignored it.  Stunning how the removal of the project template almost instantly produced wide-spread bad code, everybody is getting this wrong.

Comment: you saved my day, thank you!
the first piece of code is the VS default, however.
it works fine unless you try to allocate/deallocate memory in your constructor/destructor.