# Opening forms show function. Visual Studio c++

Tags: forms, visual-studio, user-interface, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli

I have main window.
main.cpp

```
#include "mainWindow.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

int main()
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Client::mainWindow mainWin;
    Application::Run(%mainWin);
    return 0;
}
```

And i have another form, which should open when the main form openning:

mainWindow.h

```
private: System::Void mainWindow_Shown(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        Client::logForm^ myForm = gcnew logForm();
        myForm->Show();
        //Client::logForm logF;
        //logF.Show();
    }
```

And my question: why using the commented code, the form opens and closes immediately, but uncommented code works good?

Thank you!

Comment: It is an undefined behaviour for C++ . Possible duplicate  :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360501/c-function-called-without-object-initialization

Comment: no, it is not a duplicate question.

Comment: You don't understand how stack semantics work, you got it wrong both in your Main() method and the commented code.  Read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28686756/17034).