# First steps with VS2015, using C++. Managed/Unmanaged Classes error. What I'm doing wrong?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, managed-c++

I've developed a personal project using C++Builder 2006 at work.
Now i want to develop it at home, using free stuffs. So I installed Visual Studio 2015 (as a second choice, as i failed to make Codelite+wxWidgets working) and started a new solution/ CLR project.

But i'm banging my head against an error.
This is what i have;

cSQSequencer class, created using the Add->Class wizard.

**cSQSequencer.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class cSQSequencer
{
public:
    cSQSequencer();
    ~cSQSequencer();
    std::string         Name;
    void    Reset() {
        Name="";
    };
};
```

**cSQSequencer.cpp**

```
#include "cSQSequencer.h"

cSQSequencer::cSQSequencer()
{
}

cSQSequencer::~cSQSequencer()
{
}
```

Then i have a form, i searched a way to add my class using some wizard like for adding functions, but i've found anything, so i manually added the lines related to my class:

**SysExExpMainForm**

```
#pragma once
#include "cSQSequencer.h"

namespace EnsoniqSQKSSysExexporter {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Riepilogo per SysExExpMainForm
    /// </summary>

    public ref class SysExExpMainForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        cSQSequencer SQSeq;
        SysExExpMainForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: aggiungere qui il codice del costruttore.
            //
            SQSeq.Reset();
        }

    protected:
    [ all the other code that follows.... ]
```

The error is in the line "cSQSequencer SQSeq;". It says (more or less, translated back from italian) "A member of a managed class cannot be a non-managed type".

What should i do?
Is that the proper way to add a class variable in a form?
Or should i start a different type of project (but this is the only one i found where i can add a Form....)

Comment: The "Form Designer" is only for .NET code, that saves them having to write a separate version for C++.  There is a GUI designer (called "Dialog" editor, not "Forms") for native C++, but not all editions have it.  C++/CLI form code can use normal C++ classes, but only as pointers.  For example using [my smart pointer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1695/2150) you can write `clr_scoped_ptr<cSQSequencer> SQSeq;`, create an instance of your class in the form constructor, and then use it normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    cSQSequencer SQSeq;
```

The error message you got is accurate for this declaration, using native C++ objects as members of a garbage collected object, like Form, is very, very dangerous.  Dangerous enough that the language extension completely forbids it.

The perhaps non-obvious thing that happens with garbage collected objects is that they can get moved in memory.  This happens when the collector *compacts* the heap after a collection pass.  Compaction makes the heap very efficient, improving locality of reference and preventing fragmentation.

Any pointers to such a moved object are updated by the collector to re-point them to the moved object.  But that can only work for pointers that the collector knows about.  Managed pointers.  Not pointers used by native C++ objects, they'll still point to where such a native object used to live.  Now pointing to garbage.  There is not much danger of that in your current cSQSequencer class, that we can see anyway, but that might not stay that way.  Note that the std::string member is already a problem, a template class that internally contains a pointer to the underlying string buffer.

Too dangerous, the compiler outright forbids it.  What you must use instead is a pointer or a reference to the native object.  It now refers to memory that is not allocated from the GC heap and is therefore stable.  So you'll need:

```
    cSQSequencer* SQSeq;
```

And do the dance to create and destroy it:

```
    MyForm(void) : SQSeq(new cSQSequencer) {
        // etc... 
    }

    ~MyForm() {
        delete SQSeq;
        SQSeq = nullptr;
        // etc..
    }

    !MyForm() {
        delete SQSeq;
    }
```

Note the *finalizer* for the class, `!MyForm()`, it ensure that cleanup happens regardless of whether the client code properly disposes the object.  Or to put it another way, if it forgets to use the `delete` operator then the finalizer ensures that it will happen anyway.  There is no equivalent for that in native C++.  Technically you can omit it in this specific case, Form objects have a pretty good guarantee for getting disposed, the Winforms runtime sees to it.  But make it a habit to include it anyway, you won't have to be disappointed some day.

This code probably screams "smart pointer" to you.  Examples are [Nish's CAutoNativePtr](https://voidnish.wordpress.com/2006/01/20/a-managed-smart-pointer-for-using-native-objects-in-managed-code/) and [Kenny Kerr's AutoPtr](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/Mixing-Native-and-Managed-Types-in-C_2B002B00_).

Also read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188757/how-do-i-create-a-c-cli-winforms-app-in-vs2012/15190400#15190400) to know how to properly transmogrify a console app project template to support a UI.  There's a lot of [buggy sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686486/why-is-destructor-for-a-form-called-twice) out there that gets this wrong, also the reason you should not omit the SQSeq = nullptr assignment in the destructor.  Very unlike native C++, the destructor can run more than once.  Only the finalizer is guaranteed to run once.